# implicit from context bound on collection type parameter

Tags: scala, implicit, partialfunction

I have some code that streams a response by converting a `Stream` of case classes to json representations using spray.json. This works fine for a single case class, but I want to genericize it.

So I'm starting with case classes like this:

```
import spray.json._
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._
case class Item(foo: String, bar: Int)
case class Report(baz: String, stream: Stream[Item])
object Protocol { implicit val ItemFormat = jsonFormat2(Item) }
```

In my report streaming method I have code like this (highly simplified):

```
def streamReport(...) {
    import Protocol._

    val handler: PartialFunction[Try[Any], String] = {
        case Success(Report(_, stream)) =>
            stream.head.toJson.compactPrint
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do is genericize `Report` to support more than Item:

```
case class Report[T](baz: String, stream: Stream[T])
```

But now, of course, the `streamReport` method can't find a `JsonWriter` in scope for type `Any`.

I can do something close to what I want if I add a type parameter with context bound to `streamReport`, and pass in the `Report` directly:

```
def jsonStream[T : JsonWriter](report: Report[T]): String = 
    implicitly[JsonWriter[T]].write(report.stream.head).compactPrint
```

However, I cannot figure out how to get this to work with the `PartialFunction`. The following does not compile (and wouldn't fit exactly anyway as the signature of the partial function is different than above):

```
def handler[T : JsonWriter](): PartialFunction[T, String] = {
    case Success(Report(_, stream)) =>
        implicitly[JsonWriter[T]].write(report.stream.head).compactPrint
}
```

I'm not sure where it's going wrong. Does it have to do with type erasure, or a problem with having `Try[Any]` as the parameter type on my partial function? How can I get the implicit JsonWriter I need for the element type of the stream?

Comment: Should `handler` really be `PartialFunction[Try[Report[T]], String]` ?

Comment: m-z: Perhaps, although I'm trying to work in existing code that is used for other stuff which uses other types, requiring the use of `Any`. Is it possible to somehow map between the two different `PartialFunction` signatures?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your last sentence. However, if you're trying to match on other types that don't depend on the type parameter `T`, you're probably going to run into trouble with type erasure. Hard to say without more detail of what is being matched.

Comment: The code I'm trying to refactor is part of a framework where responses are returned by Actors, and this code (and other similar method) is returning a partial function that is used to build handlers for those responses. In this particular case (for this handler) the only thing that can possibly be returned is a `Report[T]`, but in the larger scope, there are other actors which return other things, so the partial function signature takes an `Any`.

Comment: I guess the thing is, regardless of what the partial function signature is,inside the actual match block we know it's got a `Report`. Even though we don't know `T` I'd hope we could use that `implicitly` trick to get the `JsonWriter`, but we can't.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `Any` is not the problem, the problem is trying to match `case Success(Report(_, stream))`, after the definition for `Report` is now `Report[T]`.

Also, in order to find the right implicit conversion, the compiler needs to understand the type involved (in compile time). Try using something like this:

```
def streamReport[T](...) {
    import Protocol._

    val handler: PartialFunction[Try[Any], String] = {
        case Success(Report[T](_, stream)) =>
            stream.head.toJson.compactPrint
    }
}
```

That way, the compiler will know what is being matched, and can infer the right type.